# Tkinter Radio button not changing variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I'm trying to use a radio button to change a variable to base a conversion between miles and kilometers and it maintains the conversion to kilometers no matter if kilometers or miles is selected.

Relevent part of the code:

```
if Conversion_distance > 0:
        if Conversion_option == 0:
            Conversion_distance = Conversion_distance * 1.609344
            Label_converted_distance_output.configure(text = Conversion_distance)
        
        elif Conversion_option == 1:
            Conversion_distance = Conversion_distance * 0.62137
            Label_converted_distance_output.configure(text = Conversion_distance)

#------------------------------------------------------
Conversion_option = 0

Radiobutton_kilometers = Radiobutton(text = "Kilometers", variable = Conversion_option, value = 0, command = SEL)
Radiobutton_kilometers.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

Radiobutton_miles = Radiobutton(text = "Miles", variable = Conversion_option, value = 1, command = SEL)
Radiobutton_miles.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
```

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].  Also `Conversion_option` should be a tkinter variable instead, like `IntVar()`.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to use `Radiobutton`.

- Add `Stringvar()`
- Use `match case` statement
- Add keyword `value=` for "Kilometers" and "MILES"
- Use F-string format to prevent error.

You may modify it to suit your needs.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

 
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Theme Changer")
root.geometry("250x100")
root.config(bg="white")
root.grid_propagate('True')

Conversion_option = tk.StringVar(root, '1')

def print_selection():
    var = Conversion_option.get()
    match var:
        case "Kilometers":
            txt =  50 * 1.609344
        case "Miles":
            txt = 80 * 0.61
            
    Label_converted_distance_output.config(text=f'you have selected {txt}')
    

Radiobutton_kilometers = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Kilometers", variable = Conversion_option,
                                        value = "Kilometers", command = print_selection)
Radiobutton_kilometers.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

Radiobutton_miles = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Miles", variable = Conversion_option,
                                   value = "Miles", command = print_selection)
Radiobutton_miles.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

Label_converted_distance_output = tk.Label(root, width=25)
Label_converted_distance_output.grid(row=4, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]